# How to change QStackedWidget index from Qdialog

Tags: c++, qt4, qdialog

My application have an "actionhelp" in the menu bar which when clicked opens up a QDialog that contains an ok button at the other side in the mainwindow i have a QStackedWidget
So my question is how to change the index of the stackedwidget when i press that ok button in the QDialog??

Comment: Do you have something on your dialog that is important for you? Like a QLineEdit ?

Comment: No just some "text" in a label and nothimg to send from that QDialog to the mainwindow

Answer (score 2):

Signals and slots.  Connect the signal from the ok button (or emit one of your own when checking QDialog::Accepted after it closes) to a slot that will change the index in the QStackedWidget.

Example code:

Create and connect QAction in main method:

```
QAction *displayDialog = new QAction("Display Dialog", this);
connect(popup, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(showDialog()));
```

Display Dialog:

```
void showDialog()
{
    YourDialog *dialog = new YourDialog(this);
    int return_code = dialog.exec();
    if (return_code == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        int index = someValue;
        qStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a line edit on your dialog and you want to change the index of stacked widget based on the line edit value ( or a spin box ):

```
//your dialog
//the constructor
YourDialog::YourDialog(QWidget*parent)
    :QDialog(parent)
{
    connect(ur_ok_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(accept ()));
}

//access to line edit value
QString YourDialog::getUserEnteredValue(){return ur_line_edit->text();}
```

Where you create an instance of YourDialog class  :

```
 //your main window
    YourDialog dlg;
    if( dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted ){
        int i = dlg.getUserEnteredValue().toInt();
        ur_stacked_widget->setCurrentIndex(i);
    }
```

Comment: Trying that gave me this result:/home/sliver/Documents/Workspace/clinetCloud/mainwindow.cpp:34: error: cannot call constructor 'Logindialog::Logindialog' directly [-fpermissive]

Comment: maybe you've defined your constructor private.